# How do I evaluate $\int \cot^2x$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I have an integral with $\frac{1}{\tan^2x}$ needed to be evaluated. But instead of searching online for the antiderivative of $\cot^2x$, how would i find it from first principles?

Comment: One has to know some derivatives to find antiderivatives.  Unless you want to evaluate Riemann sums directly...

Comment: Oh no, by first principles, i mean like finding it by hand. I already know derivatives. I don't mean like starting with nothing. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Fundamental I have seen the link you sent me and it has helped. But now i am stuck on how he got the antiderivative for csc^2x..

Comment: That was by knowing the derivative of $\cot$. As I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

> The first thing I would suggest to learn is the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). It is a way to reduce **all** integrals of rational functions of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ to the integral of a rational function, which we always know how solve using partial fraction decomposition.

For a shorter, although less powerful approach you can write it as:

$$\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\cos(x)\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$$

Notice that the $\cos(x)$ is easy to differentiate, while the $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$ is easy to integrate. This suggests integration by parts.

$$\int\frac{\color{red}{\cos(x)}}{\sin^2(x)}=\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}$$

> Here we have used that $$\int f(g(x))\color{red}{g'(x)}dx=\int f(y)dy$$ for $y=g(x)$. In our case $g(x)=\sin(x)$, $g'(x)=\cos(x)$, and $f(y)=\frac{1}{y^2}$.

while $$(\cos(x))'=-\sin(x)$$

So, we get

$$\int\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\cos(x)\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}-\int(-\sin(x))\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}$$

There you can finish it.

> **Idea:** The integrals of the form $\int \sin^a(x)\cos^b(x)$ can be solved by combining this form of integration by parts combined with using $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. This last we didn't have to use in this particular problem, but in others it is useful to turn even powers of a $\sin$ into cosines.

Comment: i'll try this and see what happens

Comment: Ok, so i tried it by using integration by parts, but im getting -cot(x) + x + c and not -x

Comment: @XihaiLuo Either one of us missed some sign. Above I got a minus in the $-\sin(x)$, form the derivative of $\cos(x)$; a minus in $\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}$ from the integral of $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$; and finally another minus from the minus of the integration by parts $\int f(x)g'(x)=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)$. The three minuses multiplied give a $-1$. SO, I am getting $-x$

Comment: Ok, i found my error, I forgot to add the negative sign infront of the sin(x). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int \cot^2 x \, dx &= \int\csc^2x-1 \, dx = \boxed{- \cot x - x + C}
\end{align}